# Exercises for Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am new to SQL Server 2005 and I am planning to learn SSIS, SSRS and SSAS. But before going into the deep I want to master the fundamentals of SQL Server 2005. As a novice I did my best and installed these database

1. AdventureWorks
2. AdventureWorksDW

Now which is best resource from where I can master the fundamentals? I need some exercises on these databases because I understand that SQL is like Math "the more you practice the more you learn".

Also, please recommend me other database if I need to install.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend w3schools for learning sql. I've found their examples to be very simple even for a beginner and i think you will get bored pretty quickly. My suggestion is before trying to learn SSAS, SSIS, SSRS, learn the fundamentals of SQL Server as RDBMS. To that end, get some books to start learning. I suggest getting anything you can from `Itzik Ben-Gan`,

```
MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit (Exam 70-433): Microsoft SQL Server 2008 - Database Development: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Database Development (if anything, just for organizing the things you want to learn about. I think it is a great book and served me well when studying for my MCTS exam. There is also a SQL 2005 version.)
```

Don't forget Books Online (SQL Server's help). If you want help about a specific topic, this would be one of the first places to look to. For example, you might want to start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms169620.aspx and then move further.

Next thing you might want to do is follow some blogs and sign up for some news letters. I recommend [sqlservercentral.com](http://www.sqlservercentral.com). Their newsletter is great and i've found plenty of great stuff there. Spend some time following sql server and tsql server related tags in SO. Some questions are really interesting and the answers are even more so:).

As you move to more advanced topics, a must have is `Kalen Delaney SQL Server Internals Books`.

And finally, as a rule, be curious and inquisitive. Try to learn from anybody that knows more than you:). And, i think this is very important, if you have a DBA you can talk to, pick their brain as often as you can. I learn new things every day i have a chat with our senior dba and it is interesting to find out want is happening to your code and database after you've shipped it into production.

One last thing: If you are new to SQL Server, try to start with SQL Server 2008. There are differences, of course, but you will be doing it anyway, so why not start there?.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you will get lot of links for SQL for beginners if you search. Probably the best one for you to start on basics is from w3schools -

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

Since you're moving into the BI world of SQL Server, i would recommend watching the introductory webinars (For SQL Server and Business Intelligence) at http://msdev.com - they are all free and pretty decent. It might assume a basic SQL knowledge in order to fully grasp the content though.